# Where are the details defined about error code "invalid-email" and "weak-password" about createUserWithEmailAndPassword

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I'm gonna handle errors about `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` as follows;

```
class myComplete extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return TextButton(
      child: Text("Register"),
      onPressed: () async {
        try{
        final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
        final UserCredential result = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: emailController.text,
          password: maskController.text,
        );
        dialogMsg(context, result.user);
        } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e){
          //here e.code
        }
      },
      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
        foregroundColor: MyStyle.mainColor,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And I found several type of errors in related [docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/createUserWithEmailAndPassword.html) here and there were errors such as `invalid-email` and `weak-password`.

However, I could not find like what kind of RegEx adopted for email-validation or how short password is defined as weak password.
Where can I check out these default definitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The password must have at least 6 characters as in the errors thrown by Firebase SDKs and also in the Firebase Admin [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/errors).

From the [Identity Toolkit documentation](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v1/accounts/signInWithPassword),

> The length of email should be less than 256 characters and in the format of `name@domain.tld`. The email should also match the [`RFC 822`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822) addr-spec production.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful comment, and I should apologize for the late reply !